# Probability to draw two different cards each time

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> Let's assume we have two decks each comprises of $4$ different cards, let's give them numbers $1,2,3,4$ for sake of simplicity. We draw $4$ times a card from each deck without replacement.
>
> What is the probability that each time we draw two cards the cards are different? (this is a variant of the rencontre problem see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rencontres_numbers)

Of course I could simply apply the idea and the formula of the rencontre problem but I tried to approach it differently because it feels that the sample space I have defined is more intuitive.

**My approach:**

We define the sample space $\Omega$ by the set of all $4$ tuples which themselves consists of $2$ tuples. Each represents the draw of two cards, e.g. $\omega=((1,2),(2,1),(3,4),(4,3))$. Then the cardinality of $\Omega$ is $|\Omega|=(4!)^3$. If we count all possibilities where all $2$ tuples contain different cards we get $(4!)^2$. Hence the probability is $\frac{1}{4!}$.

This differs from the probability I get if I apply the formula from the wikipedia article on the rencontre numbers. Where is my mistake?

Comment: I would have thought $|\Omega|=(4!)^2= 576$ and the possible cases where all four $2$-tuples contain different cards somewhat lower (possibly $216$ if the probability is $\frac38$) though you do not seem to have calculated it

Comment: For what it's worth, I posted an answer and then deleted it.  I was misinterpreting your question, where you intend drawing (i.e. sampling) without replacement.

Comment: If we're sampling the cards w/o replacement I would have thought the answer is $\frac{!4}{4!}$

Comment: You may want to clarify your question. I am assuming you are drawing with replacement? The first time you draw one card each from both decks, the probability that both cards are different is $3/4$. The sample space is $4^2$. Now please clarify the restriction when you draw one card each from both decks the second time. If I drew $\{1, 2 \}$ the first time, can I again draw $\{1, 2 \}$ or $\{2, 1 \}$ the second time?

Comment: @Henry how did you get $216$?

Comment: $24$ ways of dealing the first deck, and for each of those $9$ ways of dealing the second deck which result in no matches. $24 \times 9=216$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to draw two different cards each time, the order of the numbers in the second pile must be a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) of the order of the numbers in the first pile.  For this to occur, there cannot be a match in the $i$th position of the pile, where $1 \leq i \leq 4$.  There are $\binom{4}{k}$ ways to have $k$ positions in the second pile in which the number on the card in the second pile matches the number on the corresponding card in the first pile and $(4 - k)!$ ways to arrange the remaining cards in the second pile.  Hence, by the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of derangements of the numbers in the first pile is
$$!4 = D_4 = \sum_{k = 0}^{4} (-1)^k\binom{4}{k}(4 - k)! = 4! - 4 \cdot 3! + 6 \cdot 2! - 4 \cdot 1! + 1 \cdot 0! = 9$$
Since there are $4!$ possible permutations of the second pile, the probability that there are no matches is
$$\Pr(\text{no matches}) = \frac{!4}{4}! \frac{D_4}{4!} = \frac{9}{24} = \frac{3}{8}$$
as Matthew H. suggested in the comments.

**Your model**

We will correct your calculations.

There are $4!$ possible orders for the four cards in each deck, so the number of elements in the sample space is $|\Omega| = (4!)^2$, as Henry said in the comments.

We can use the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to count the number of arrangements in which there are no matching pairs.

*A matching pair*:  There are four ways to select the number which matches, four ways to choose its position in the two decks, and $3!$ ways to arrange the remaining cards in each deck.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{1} \cdot 4 \cdot (3!)^2$$
arrangements in which there is a matching pair.

However, we have subtracted too much since we have subtracted each arrangement with two matching pairs twice, once for each way of designating one of those pairs as the matching pair.  We only want to subtract them once, so we must add them to the total.

*Two matching pairs*:  There are $\binom{4}{2}$ ways to select the two numbers which will appear in the matching pairs, $4$ ways to select the position in the decks for the smaller of those numbers, $3$ ways to select the position in the decks for the larger of those numbers, and $2!$ ways to arrange the remaining numbers in each deck.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{2} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot (2!)^2$$
such arrangements.

However, now we have added too much.  We first subtracted each arrangement with three matching pairs three times, once for each way of designating one of those three matching pairs as the matching pair, then added them three times, once for each of the $\binom{3}{2}$ ways of designating two of those three pairs as the matching pairs.  Therefore, we have not subtracted these cases at all, so we must subtract them from the total.

*Three matching pairs*:  There are $\binom{4}{3}$ ways to select the three numbers which will appear in the matching pairs, $4$ ways to select the position in the decks for the smallest of those numbers, $3$ ways to select the position in the decks for the next smallest of those numbers, $2$ ways to select the position in the decks for the largest of those numbers, and one way to place the remaining card in each deck.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{3} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot (1!)^2$$
such arrangements.

However, we have subtracted too much.  We first subtracted those cases with four matching pairs four times, once for each way of designating one of those four pairs as the matching pair; then we added them six times, once for each of the $\binom{4}{2}$ ways of designating two of those four pairs as the two matching pairs; and then subtracted them four times, once for each of the $\binom{4}{3}$ ways of designating three of those four pairs as the three matching pairs.  Hence, we have subtracted those arrangements with four matching pairs $4 - 6 + 4 = 2$ times.  We only want to subtract them once, so we must add them to the total.

*Four matching pairs*:  There is one way to select all four numbers to be in matching pairs, four ways to select the position of the smallest number in the decks, three ways to select the position of the next smallest number in the decks, two ways to select the position of the third smallest number in the decks, and one way to select the position of the largest number in the decks.  Hence, there are
$$\binom{4}{4}4!$$
such arrangements.

By the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, the number of favorable arrangements is
$$(4!)^2 - \binom{4}{1} \cdot 4 \cdot (3!)^2 + \binom{4}{2} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot (2!)^2 - \binom{4}{3} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot (1!)^2 - \binom{4}{4} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot (0!)^2$$
Hence, the probability that there are no matching pairs is
$$\frac{(4!)^2 - \binom{4}{1} \cdot 4 \cdot (3!)^2 + \binom{4}{2} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot (2!)^2 - \binom{4}{3} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot (1!)^2 - \binom{4}{4} \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1 \cdot (0!)^2}{(4!)^2} = \frac{216}{576}$$
as Henry predicted in the comments.

Notice that
$$\frac{216}{576} = \frac{9}{24} = \frac{D_4}{4!} = \frac{!4}{4!}$$